# Changing SocialEngine "edit my profile" page layout

Tags: socialengine

I have been all over many files in the core but can't seen to find or know how to change the "edit my profile", "browse member", "forgot password" layouts to use a default layout or set layout. they all seem to be loading directly in to the content widget..

Any help please.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Layout is only enabled for a few specific pages- specified in core_contents table in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot Password password page layout is included to the layout editor's pages list beginning from SE 4.3.0 version. Regarding "browse members" page - it can only be edited manually (`application/modules/User/views/scripts/_browseUsers.tpl` and `application/modules/User/views/scripts/index/browse.tpl`). Same situation for the "forgot password" (`application/modules/User/views/scripts/auth/forgot.tpl` and forgot-form).

Comment: Thanks a lot that was helpful.. Can you please help further.. I am trying to render the main menu widget in the "layout_top" i have just created. `$this->view->navigation = $navigation = Engine_Api::_()
      ->getApi('menus', 'core')
      ->getNavigation('core_main');` on the .tpl files but not working.

Comment: No problem. You should place code `$this->view->navigation = $navigation = Engine_Api::_() ->getApi('menus', 'core') ->getNavigation('core_main');` to controller of your widget and then render this navigation in your template using following code
`<?php foreach( $this->navigation as $item ): ?>
      <li><?php echo $this->htmlLink($item->getHref(), $this->translate($item->getLabel())) ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>`